# Lookup from CSV

Tags: c#, linq

I have a CSV file in this format:

```
"Call Type","Charge Type","Map to"
"51","","Mobile SMS"
"52","","Mobile SMS"
"DD","Local Calls","Local Calls"
"DD","National Calls","National Calls"
```

First two columns are the "source information" that my C# will insert, and the last column is what it will return.

Currently what I am doing is a switch statement hardcoded in c#.

```
var File001 = from line in File.ReadLines(bill_file)
                                      let l = line.Split(',')
                                      select new
                                      { CallType = ICD_map(l[5],l[3])}
```

where

```
l[5] = "51";
l[3] = "";



 private static string ICD_map(string call_type_description, string call_category,)
        {
              case "51":
              case "52":
                  return "Mobile SMS";
               default:
                    return "Unknown";
}
```

I want this to be an expandable list thus my new method is to load the mapping table from a csv file. Can you suggest any improvements to this method to make my definition library expandable (hoping CSV file okay for this purpose, it is only 100 lines long so far, so not concerned about memory management).

What I have tried so far is:

```
    class ICD_Map2
    {
        private string call_type;
        private string charge_type;
        private string map_to;

        // Default constructor
        public ICD_Map2() {
            call_type = "Unknown";
            charge_type = "Unknown";
            map_to = "Unknown";
        }

        // Constructor 
        public ICD_Map2(string call_type, string charge_type, string map_to)
        {
            this.call_type = call_type;
            this.charge_type = charge_type;
            this.map_to = map_to;
        }

    }

    List<ICD_Map2>maps = new List<ICD_Map2>();



private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start new thread to create BillSummary.csv
            button1.Enabled = false;

            maps.Clear();
            //load mapping file
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"Itemised_Call_Details_Map.csv"));
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                maps.Add(new ICD_Map2(values[0].Replace("\"",""), values[1].Replace("\"",""), values[2].Replace("\"","")));
                textBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + " Mapping: " + values[0].Replace("\"", "") + " to " + values[1].Replace("\"", ""));
            }
```

I have loaded the CSV file to my program but I am unable to do the lookup from LINQ. Can you tell me the next process.

Open to any other method.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think it would be of benefit to describe what you end goal is. Depending on what you're looking for, there are many suggestions that could be made. I guess my confusion comes from the example data that has duplicate calltypes mapped to different charge types.

Comment: @KreepN I am trying to create a function that will take in two variables, match it with the first two columns in the CSV and if 100% match return the 3rd column from the CSV.

Comment: I understand that, and you have provided the csv mapping file at top. What would be your end result, a collection of objects representing your data? A file with your results? (It would be helpful to know what bill_file is too))

Comment: @KreepN I am going to generate another CSV file based on the: mapping csv and bill that I am trying to map

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

It will give you lots of flexibility to play around with your code.

We have been using it in our projects, and it's really helpful to have full control inplace of writing generic CSV code which is prone to errors and bugs